# REPEAT UNTIL Loop Syntax Error

Tags: python

I'm still getting a handle on python and have been trying to implement a REPEAT UNTIL loop using online tutorials. Everything seems to be in order but I keep getting a syntax error but I absolutely cannot find an error with my syntax! Can someone help me? My code is;

```
while detvar != "SABRE":
            REPEAT 
            detvar=input("Please Pass a Valid Detector or Parameter Set");
           UNTIL detvar = "SABRE"
```

detvar is my string variable the error is for the 'detvar' on the last line.

Comment: Please provide a link to the tutorials that say `REPEAT` is a valid Python keyword.

Comment: No way, dude! This is Pascal-like syntax, not Python! Please stop trying to write code and read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/) first!

Comment: Please also include the error message.

Comment: It doesn't work because python doesn't support that syntax.

Comment: The error message was just "invalid syntax". But if repeat/until isn't relevant for Python than that makes complete sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need:

```
detvar = "" # allow for at least one iteration
while detvar != "SABRE":
    detvar=input("Please Pass a Valid Detector or Parameter Set")
```

`REPEAT` and `UNTIL` are not valid expressions in Python. Instead, you want to use [`while condition != value`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement), which is what you originally had.

The `while` statement allows you to continue iterating as long as a condition holds true. Alternatively, you can repeat until something is true by negating the condition.

So, `while detvar != "SABRE":` iterates the body of the loop (which is everything indented under the colon) until `detvar` is equal to `"SABRE"`.

---

Edit: In accordance with Bryan Oakley's comment, `detvar` is initialized as a value that is not `"SABRE"` so that the loop body executes at least once.

Comment: this isn't exactly the same. The repeat guarantees at least one iteration, whereas your solution does not (unless detvar is explicitly set to something other than `"SABRE"`)

Comment: Using your answer, I have gotten it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a horribly worded question, and I have no idea what this code is meant to accomplish, but I'll see if I can decipher this. There's no need to use "REPEAT," just do

```
while devtar != "SABRE":
    devtar = input("Please Pass.(whatever this is).. Set")
```

It should exit the loop when devtar = "SABRE" automatically.